# XPages - partial refresh inside a table

Tags: html, ajax, xpages, lotus-notes

I would like to define an area **inside a table** on an XPage and then partially refresh this area when a button is clicked. I have no problem using partial refresh with a panel but I do not know how I can define an area to be refreshed which is inside a table. I have tried unsuccessfully with "div" and "xp:span" tags to define such an area. Here is what I am doing:

```
<xp:table>
<xp:div id="RefreshAreaID">
<xp:tr>
<xp:td>
<xp:label value="Row 3" id="label3"></xp:label></xp:td>
<xp:td></xp:td>
</xp:tr>
<xp:tr>
<xp:td>
<xp:label value="Row 4" id="label4"></xp:label></xp:td>
<xp:td></xp:td>
</xp:tr>
</xp:div>
```

When I add the xp:div tags, I no longer see the rows and cells it contain on the XPages design editor.

Answer (score 3):

Use `xp:div` with an `id` and then inside the `xp:div` you add the content to be refreshed.

**Update:** Now that you have added your source code I can recommend that you refresh the entire table. So add an id to the table and then refresh that component:

```
<xp:table id="RefreshAreaID">
<xp:tr>
<xp:td>
<xp:label value="Row 3" id="label3"></xp:label></xp:td>
<xp:td></xp:td>
</xp:tr>
<xp:tr>
<xp:td>
<xp:label value="Row 4" id="label4"></xp:label></xp:td>
<xp:td></xp:td>
</xp:tr>
...
</xp:table>
```

You can also look into refreshing several table rows by [chaining the partial refreshes](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh#Run+multiple+partial+updates).

Comment: I'm trying to use xp:div, however the fields are no longer visible on the design tab when I do this. Inside the xp:div I am including xp:tr and xp:td tags.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The table contains some required fields, if I refresh the entire table this will trigger the validation for those fields. If there is no other solutions, I will split the one table I now have into separate tables. This, however, is what I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: I understand your problem. You could also chain your partial refreshes to refresh several table rows: http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh#Run+multiple+partial+updates

Comment: Why don't you just disable validation for that event? See my updated answer.

Comment: Chaining partial refreshes doesn't work either. Rows should be hidden or visible based on the value of a Dojo Filtering Select field. If the row is hidden, changing the value of the Dojo Filtering Select gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

As Per Henrik already said you could use a div. or if you still want to work with tables try this:

```
<xp:panel tagName="table" id="tableId">
    <xp:panel tagName="tr" id="trId">
        <xp:panel tagName="td" id="tdId"></xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:panel>
```

You should be able to refresh the whole table using "tableId", the table Row using "trId" or only the td using "tdId".

Comment: Thanks, what I want to do is refresh several rows inside a table. How do I do that?

Comment: What about using xp:panel tagName="tbody" to group a set of rows? I didn't tested that, but it feels like this could work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can mix tags like that. Suggestions:

1. Refresh the rows you need one by one.
2. If there are really many rows to be refreshed split your table to multiple tables and refresh the whole table.
3. Use `colspan` to make one full width cell. Add a new table inside that cell and refresh that. (edit)

**EDIT**

Based on your comments the only problem is validation. Check "[x] Process data without validation" check box in your button event to disable validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I really was hoping to avoid that. HTML has a "tbody" tag which allows "tr" tags to be grouped, however XPages has no "xp:tbody" tag.

Comment: I do want to validate some fields inside the table.

Comment: OK some fields need to be validated and some not. See 3. in my answer.

Comment: I could do as you say in point three but what advantage does that give me over just splitting my one table into several tables?

Comment: You are right, it's just an option. This way you can refresh both tables by refreshing the main table if you ever need to.

Comment: I would strongly urge a decreased reliance on the Design tab. Nearly every "right" way of doing things in XPages reduces the ability of the visual editor to accurately reflect what the users will actually see.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean Tim.

Comment: I meant to leave this as a comment to Per's answer, because you commented on that answer (and in your question) that if you use `<xp:div/>` tags, the table contents no longer show up in the design tab. That editor is woefully insufficient and in some cases downright misleading. So a functional approach that meets the need at runtime should not be overlooked on the basis that it negatively impacts the display of the design tab.